# PHP Doctrine описание сущностей для получения полей из таблицы связи в отношениях many-to-many

Tags: php, orm, doctrine, many-to-many

Имеется две таблицы Товар (product) и Свойство (property), связанные отношением many-to-many через таблицу связи (product_properties). product_properties имеет три поля: product_id, property_id и value. Первые два поля - ключи из соответствующих таблиц, а третье - некоторое значение.
Я создал два класса сущностей Doctrine:

```
/*
 * @Table(name="product")
 * @Entity
 */
class Product {
    /**
     * @ManyToMany(targetEntity=Property::class, inversedBy="products")
     * @JoinTable(
     *      name="products_properties",
     *      joinColumns={ @JoinColumn(name="product_id", referencedColumnName="id") },
     *      inverseJoinColumns={ @JoinColumn(name="property_id", referencedColumnName="id") }
     * )
     */
    private $productProperties;

    public function getProductProperties() {
        return $this->productProperties;
    }
}

/**
 * @Entity
 * @Table(name="property")
 */
class Property
{
    /**
     * @ORM\ManyToMany(targetEntity=Product::class, mappedBy="productProperties")
     */
    private $products;
}
```

Каким образом можно сделать так, чтобы при запросе

```
$result = $em->getRepository(Product::class)->find($id)->getProductProperties();
```

в выдаче также было значение поля value из связующей таблицы (из product_properties)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Many-to-many служит только для связи между сущностями. т.е. в связующей таблице будут только идентификаторы связанных сущностей. Если вам нужны какие-то ещё данные в связи (например, количество), вам нужно делать промежуточную сущность для связи.

т.е у вас будет 3 сущности - `Product`, `Property` и `ProductProperty`. Отношения будут `Product --(one to many)--> ProductProperty` и `Property --(one to many)--> ProductProperty`.

Получить значения свойств можно будет примерно так:

```
<?php
foreach ($product->getProductProperties() as $productProperty) {
    $productProperty->getProperty()->getName(); // Название свойства
    $productProperty->getValue(); // Значение свойства
}
```

Comment: Да, совершенно верно, Я к такому же выводу пришёл. Doctrine не поддерживает такую возможность. Если же нужно уменьшить количество запросов, то единственный выход - создавать сущность ProductProperties (поля из Property + поле value) и делать именованый запрос (https://www.doctrine-project.org/projects/doctrine-orm/en/2.7/reference/annotations-reference.html#annref_named_native_query), ProductProperties можно сделать наследником от Property.